# MS SQL Server 2008 "with (nolock)" equivalent for IBM DB2 9.7

Tags: sql-server, db2, nolock

In MS SQL Server 2008 you can write like this:

```
FROM EMPLOYEE as A with (nolock)
```

Is there an equivalent syntax for DB2 9.7? Thanks

Comment: `NOLOCK` is a shortcut for setting the *Read Uncommitted* [Transaction Isolation Level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149.aspx). The DB2 equivalent appears to be [UR (Uncommitted Read)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0004121.html).

Comment: apparently the DB2 equivalent would be `WITH UR`. See [Specifying the isolation level](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0004121.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DB2: Uncomitted Read = WITH UR

```
SELECT * FROM whatevertable WITH UR
```